# simple_form clickable value using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, link-to

hopefully a simple question.

Is it possible to make the value of a simple_form field a link_to?

I have tried

```
 = f.input link_to(:project_id,project_path(@project_action_plan.project_id)), readonly: true
```

and also

```
= f.input :project_id, :input_html => {:value => link_to @project_action_plan.project_id, project_path(@project_action_plan.project_id)}, readonly: true
```

But am not getting the desired result.

Google only really brings up [this stackoverflow result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238721/how-to-add-html-link-for-a-simple-form-field-in-rails-3-2) which was more about then using ajax etc and the simple_form Github doesn't mention anything. I am thinking it may not be possible and that I will have to make the label clickable.

Comment: You want a link, not a field, right? Just use `link_to` directly.

Comment: I have done that for the meantime with a link_to button. I just thought by keeping it as a field I can keep the layout consistent with the other fields.

Comment: tadman is right.  Just use link_to.  It is not a form option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the helper methods work is very specific. If you want to write your own custom helper then it's possible to create your own arbitrary formatter methods by creating a subclass of FormBuilder and using that when rendering your forms.

More information on this subject is available in [the documentation on Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).